# a request for the moderators please?

Tags: discussion

my question on is the [classical world an illusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50051/2451) is depressing me. I made a mistake in asking it and the replies are getting me down. Could the moderators please for me, delete the question or close it down. I asked it, I got a number of answers and now I want them to end.

thank you for your appreciation.

Lee Hudson

Comment: You could have flagged that question... that goes to moderators.

Comment: mods can you please close or delete the question for me, deleting it would really put my mind at ease as it is really upsetting me

Comment: Short answer: no. Askers can delete their own question only while they have no positively voted answers after which there are other users with a stake in the fate of the question.

Comment: This guy seems to be in the middle of a depression, expressed by means of this sort of existentialism crisis. Nobody here knows what may be the details in his life, but he is seems to be suffering a lot. I guess the users that posted answers could give their permission so that the question could be erased.

Comment: If you want, we _can_ dissociate the post from your account. Just give us a list of which posts/comments you want dissociated.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this site isn't *just* for you to get answers. The answers should be availible to others to read, and people should be able to contribute their own answers if they feel like something is missing. So we won't delete a good post just because you're finished with it.

You *can* delete your own question if it has no positively voted answers, though.

Out of curiosity, could you elaborate why you want it to be deleted?